# What does the iterative version of randomized select do?

Tags: algorithm

I found the code for iterative version of randomized-select online:

```
RANDOMIZED-SELECT(A,p,r,i)
    while p < r do
        q ← RANDOMIZED-PARTITION(A,p,r)
        k ← q – p +1

        if i ≤ k then
            r ← q
        else
            p ← q + 1
            i ← i – k

    return p
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could explain to me what the part of the code from if i<=k to the end does? What does it do differently from the recursive version?

Comment: What language? It should be tagged. In any event, presumably the answer would depend on what `RANDOMIZED-PARTITION` does. Perhaps you could tell us what that is.

Comment: @JohnColeman: This looks like pseudocode from "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen et al. The algorithm is a randomized "find the `i`th smallest element in an array", also known as [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect); `RANDOMIZED-PARTITION` picks a random element and partitions the array based on whether elements are less/equal to or greater than that element, and then returns the index of the last element of the left partition. (But yes, the OP should have stated this.)

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset Thanks. I thought that it might be pseudo-code, but it also looks like it could have been from some computer algebra system. Your answer is nice and is worthy of an upvote.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Thanks! Yeah, that book is extremely thorough, so they went for a pretty rigorous pseudocode as well (now I almost feel like writing a compiler for it...) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p` and `r` are the left and right indices of the range of `A` within which you are searching for the `i`th element. After the first partitioning, you check how many elements are in each of the two partitions. If there are `i` elements or more in the left partition (as indicated by `k`), you need to continue the search there, in which case you need to adjust the right end of your range (`r`) to be equal to the split point between the partitions (`q`). If not, the element you are looking for will be somewhere in the right partition, and so you need to set the left end of your range (`p`) to the element just to the right of the split (`q + 1`) - and since your range has now shifted to the right, you need to adjust `i` relative to that (if you were originally looking for the 8th element, and there are 3 elements in the left partition, you must now look for the 5th element in the right partition).

This adjustment of the indices must also be done in the recursive version, but it typically happens in the recursive call, and so it might look something like `RANDOMIZED-SELECT(A, q + 1, r, i - k)` in the second case.

Comment: @useruser1412: Glad it made sense!